# How to assign multiple author names for one article?

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there any way to mention two or more author names for a particular article in Drupal 7?

I need to add two author names for one article.

I tried to add two author names in the `Author` text box, separating them by commas, but it did not allow me to do this.

Is there any module or other way to do this?

Comment: For future reference, the authors of the References module now recommend the **Entity Reference module:** http://drupal.org/project/entityreference

Comment: Where do the authors make that recommendation? Could you add a link to that recommendation please.

Answer (score 3):

My workaround for this would be to enable a user reference field with multiple allowed values on the content type you want to put multiple authors on. Then just disable display of authoring info on that content type and instead display the user reference fields.

There are some things that you can't do with this but if you just want to display or categorize posts by multiple authors I think this will work fine.

Comment: How to enable multiple author on in user reference module.I installed user reference module but it is allowing only one user to select

Comment: Can u help me beth.

Comment: In the field settings, I think you can change the number of submissions for that field. If you change it to "unlimited" then you get a button to add another when you're filling it in. If that doesn't work, you can add multiple fields of the same type on your content type.

Comment: But how do I get Drupal enter the user information into it automatically when a user edits a node / adds more data into the node?

Comment: @Raj I think what you're talking about is more like revision history. You could pull the revision history and cull the owner of each revision. If you don't have automatic creation of a new revision enabled on the content type settings, that needs to be enabled first.

Comment: I do have automatic revision creation. But how do I pull the author information from each revision? Also that might cause redundancy of the same user too, because a same user might edit the content time and over again. Some coding has to be done to achieve this? I have started a new question for this, please check it: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51063/including-multiple-authors-in-authoring-information-for-a-drupal-7-node

Answer (score 0):

Drupal provides the two contribute module for multiple author name to assign single article.
`Entity Reference` module and `user Reference` module.

Answer (score 0):

Organic Groups may be a good way to deal with this.

Comment: Definitely not. That is a huge module and only a tiny part of it, entity references, is what's needed.