# Including multiple authors in Authoring information for a Drupal 7 node

Tags: nodes, entities, users

I have a CMS to which many people can possibly provide data. So, I would want to include all the users who have contributed the data for a node by adding new data or moderating existing data, because everyone who contributed for a node deserve themselves to be undersigned. Right now, only the first person who creates the content would be the rightful author.

How can I achieve this?

I have googled but could not get much help. The closest I could [find was this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30501/multiple-author-names-for-one-article-in-drupal-7), which still goes unanswered. I have checked [Entity Reference module](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) but I could not get it to auto-fill the author whenever a user edits an existing node.

I have automatic revisions enabled, which means I do have the information of each author for a node who have contributed. But how do I pull each author out of the revision information and display the collection of all authors & contributors in a nice manner at the end of each article?

Please help me find a solution, I am not that well versed with PHP programming.

Thanks & Regards,
Raj Pawan G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I accomplished this by the following steps:

1. Download and enable the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and the [Entity Reference module](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference).
2. Add a field called "Foo" to your content type. Field type: Entity Reference. Target type: user.
3. Create a new Rule.

   1. Add event: "Before saving content"
   2. Add condition: Data comparison. Parameter: Data to compare: [node:type], Data value: bar (Where "bar" = your content type's name)
   3. Add action: Add an item to a list. List: [node:field-foo], Item to add: [site:current-user]

Now every time content is saved, the user who saved it will be added to the list of editors of that page.

Comment: Awesome answer! It is almost perfect, but at the end I would want to show the User's name who contributed, but what is displayed is the User's history, "about me" etc. which are configured in the Configuration->People->Account Settings->Manage Display. How do I fix this last thing? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Change the display mode on the "manage display" tab of the content type settings.

Comment: Awesome, I should have checked that! Accepting your answer. Well one more thing if am not asking for too much! Username is sort of cryptic, so I have added a display name to the users fields and marked it as required field. Now instead of showing this username, is there a way to show the display name instead? I tried a lot but could not find any options for that.

Comment: Also small correction, please change your 3.2. from Add event to Add action.

Comment: Changed. I don't understand the question in your previous comment.

Comment: What I meant in my previous question is, right now the author's being shown is the default "username" which the user will be providing when s/he created the account. I would rather like to display the "Screen name" of the user instead of his "username". I checked thoroughly and there seems no way to do it. I think this is fine, anyhow visitors can get to click the user's link to see user details.

Comment: Options for this include programming an additional display format, editing the template file for the nodetype, or using something like a view to pull the info you want to see and hiding the field itself, or using the Contemplate module to alter the output. This should be a separate question if you want further detail.

Comment: I am fine with what I have now, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Raj: Couldn't you choose which fields to display in the display formatter of user? You could hide the username and show your custom field.

Comment: @beth: This wouldn't work for old nodes/revisions, right? Maybe worth a note.

Comment: There's no way I know of to do this retroactively. Node_save() saved the global $user as the revision owner if revisions are turned on, so you could potentially create a view of revision owners if revisions were enabled. If not, the data is lost forever.

Comment: A small note:In Drupal 7, Entity Reference is a field that requires a module.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom .module that does the task for a content type called wiki_page. The content type has a multi-valued text field called field_editors. Put field_editors on a display mode, and the list will appear. No Views work needed.

`/**
 * @file
 * Keep track of the users who have edited a wiki page.
 * 
 * @todo Check whether the page content has changed.
 */`

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_alter().
 */
function cyco_remember_editors_form_wiki_page_node_form_alter( &$form, $form_state ) {
  $form['#submit'][] = '_cyco_remember_editors_wiki_submit';
  $form['field_editors']['#access'] = FALSE;
}

/**
 * Add current user to list of editors if not already there.
 */
function _cyco_remember_editors_wiki_submit( $form, &$form_state ) {
  global $user;
  //Editor is current user.
  $editor_name = $user->name;
  //Flag to show whether the editor is already in the list.
  $editor_in_list = FALSE;
  $language = $form['#entity']->language;
  $num_editors = 0;
  //Are any editors listed?
  if ( isset($form['#entity']->field_editors[$language][0]['value']) ) {
    //Yes - see whether the current editor is already in the list.
    $current_values = $form['#entity']->field_editors[$language];
    $num_editors = sizeof( $current_values );
    for( $index = 0; $index < $num_editors; $index ++ ) {
      if ( $current_values[$index]['value'] == $editor_name ) {
        //Editor is already listed.
        $editor_in_list = TRUE;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if ( ! $editor_in_list ) {
    //Current editor is not in the list. Add him/her.
    $form_state['values']['field_editors'][$language][$num_editors]['value']
        = $editor_name;
  }
}